# Doesn't print index

Tags: indexing

I can't seem to solve my issue. I don't know what's wrong with my code, it wont print the index in the final pdf, my code is (I've got an extra .tex with a chapter, where i've got several `\index[terms]{something}`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,spanish]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,footskip=.7cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{imakeidx}%for indexes
\makeindex[name=terms,title=\'Indice alfab\'etico,columns=2]
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}


\usepackage{pifont}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.0001in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{.0001in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.8in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{.0001in}




\def\I{{\cal I}}


\renewcommand{\nomname}{Notaci\'on}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\ding{110}}

\newcommand{\uprint}[2]{
  \overline{\int_{#1}^{#2}}
}
\newcommand{\lorint}[2]{
  \underline{\int_{#1}^{#2}}}

\DeclareMathOperator\erf{erf}

\newenvironment{rcases}
  {\left.\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}\right\rbrace}

  \newenvironment{dedication}
{
   \cleardoublepage
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
   \hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth}
   \raggedright
   \itshape
}%
{
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace*{\stretch{3}}
   \clearpage
}


  \makeatletter
\def\maketitle{%
  \null
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \vfill
  \begin{center}\leavevmode
    \normalfont
    {\LARGE\raggedleft \@author\par}%
    \hrulefill\par
    {\huge\raggedright \@title\par}%
    \vskip 1cm
%    {\Large \@date\par}%
  \end{center}%
  \vfill
  \null
  \cleardoublepage
  }
\makeatother
\author{Sebasti\'an N\'ajera Valencia}
\title{Notas de C\'alculo III 2017-1}
\date{ }



\setcounter{chapter}{0}



\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

% Length to control the \fancyheadoffset and the calculation of \headline
% simultaneously
\newlength\FHoffset
\setlength\FHoffset{0cm}

\addtolength\headwidth{2\FHoffset}

\fancyheadoffset{\FHoffset}

% these lengths will control the headrule trimming to the left and right 
\newlength\FHleft
\newlength\FHright

% here the trimmings are controlled by the user
\setlength\FHleft{0cm}
\setlength\FHright{-1.5cm}

% The new definition of headrule that will take into acount the trimming(s)
\newbox\FHline
\setbox\FHline=\hbox{\hsize=\paperwidth%
  \hspace*{\FHleft}%
  \rule{\dimexpr\headwidth-\FHleft-\FHright\relax}{\headrulewidth}\hspace*{\FHright}%
}
\renewcommand\headrule{\vskip-.7\baselineskip\copy\FHline}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\include{tex/cap1}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\'Indice alfab\'etico}
\printindex[terms]



\begin{thebibliography}{99}

  \bibitem{apostol}
T. ~Apostol, (2001). \emph{Calculus, Vol. II.} M\'exico. Revert\'e.

  \bibitem{Bartle}
R.~Bartle, (1976). \emph{The Elements of Real Analysis.} Estados Unidos. Wiley.

  \bibitem{choquet}
Y.~Choquet-Bruhat, C. ~DeWitt-Morette (1982). \emph{Analysis, Manifolds and Physics, Part 1: Basics.} Estados Unidos. North Holland.

  \bibitem{devinatz}
A. ~Devinatz (1968). \emph{Advanced Calculus.} Estados Unidos. Holt, Rinehart and Winston.

  \bibitem{edwards}
H. ~Edwards (1994). \emph{Advanced Calculus: A Differential Forms Approach.} Estados Unidos. Birkh\"auser.

  \bibitem{fleming}
W. ~Fleming (1987). \emph{Functions of Several Variables (Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics).} Estados Unidos. Springer.

  \bibitem{lang}
S. ~Lang (1996). \emph{Calculus of Several Variables (Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics).} Estados Unidos. Springer.

  \bibitem{loomis} 
L.~Loomis, S. ~Sternberg, (1990). \emph{Advanced Calculus.} Estados Unidos. Johns \& Bartlett Publishing.

  \bibitem{munkres}
J. ~Munkres, (2008). \emph{Analysis on Manifolds.} Estados Unidos. Westview Press.

  \bibitem{nicker}
H.K. ~Nickerson, D.C. ~Spencer, N.E. ~Steenrod (2011). \emph{Advanced Calculus.} Estados Unidos. Dover.

  \bibitem{oneill}
B. ~O'Neill, (1972). \emph{Elementos de Geometr\'ia Diferencial.} M\'exico. Limusa.

  \bibitem{spivak}
M. ~Spivak, (2004). \emph{C\'alculo en Variedades.} M\'exico. Revert\'e.

\end{thebibliography}

\nocite{*}
\bibliography{aipsamp}% Produces the bibliography via BibTeX.

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  what you have here can hardly be called a "minimum" (non)working example.  and it doesn't contain any of your `\index` entries (they are most likely in the `\include`d file), so it's futile to try to compile it.  please construct a small subset of this file, with only the essential packages, a small amount of text that includes some `\index` entries, and post it here instead of the present file.  it should be cut-and-pastable so we can actually compile it to see what's happening.

Comment: Use `\index[terms]{<index entry>}` if you want to write to `terms.idx`.  (Would've been helpful if you stripped down your example first, as suggested.)

Comment: `\index{foo}` won't work if there's no typesetting content in the file.